# Why NODE_DEBUG=fs environment variable is set but not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

Node.js docs about a `fs` module says (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system):

> To get a trace to the original call site, set the NODE_DEBUG environment variable:

And an example of setting an `fs` env variable:

```
$ env NODE_DEBUG=fs node script.js
fs.js:66
    throw err;
          ^
Error: EISDIR, read
at rethrow (fs.js:61:21)
at maybeCallback (fs.js:79:42)
at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:153:18)
at bad (/path/to/script.js:2:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/script.js:5:1)
<etc.>
```

However, if I set `fs` env variable upfront in command line or using `process.env` in the script, the variable is set but doesn't work, no trace is shown:

Upfront in command line:

```
$ env NODE_DEBUG=fs // set before running a script
$ node script.js // doesn't bring the trace
```

In the script:

```
'use strict';
process.env.NODE_DEBUG = 'fs'; // set it on the second line of a script

<...> // script goes here
```

I both cases the result is as follows, no trace, though NODE_DEBUG=fs is set:

```
fs.js:81
      throw err;  // Forgot a callback but don't know where? Use NODE_DEBUG=fs
        ^
Error: EISDIR, read
    at Error (native)
```

The question is. 
Why command line inline variable setting works:

`$ env NODE_DEBUG=fs node script.js`,

but other ways of setting it do not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`env` runs a program with a particular environment. If it isn’t passed one, it lists environment variables instead; it can’t modify its parent process’s enivronment. To *set* an environment variable for the current session, use `export`:

```sh
export NODE_DEBUG=fs
node script.js
```

Shells will let you omit both `export` and `env`, though:

```sh
NODE_DEBUG=fs node script.js # Like env; doesn’t create an exported NODE_DEBUG
NODE_DEBUG=fs
node script.js
```

Comment: Also, the reason setting the environment variable within the script doesn't work is because the bootstrapping process has already called the debug logging function (before the script is even executed) which only evaluates `process.env.NODE_DEBUG` [once](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7d14dd9b5e78faabb95d454a79faa513d0bbc2a5/lib/util.js#L57-L58).

Comment: @mscdex True, but `fs` module decides like [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7d14dd9b5e78faabb95d454a79faa513d0bbc2a5/lib/fs.js#L36), right?

Comment: I do not understand. Within a script I set `process.env.NODE_DEBUG='fs'` before any `require` commands. `var fs = require('fs')` follows after `process.env.NODE_DEBUG='fs'`. The docs about `process.env` says: _You can write to this object, but changes won't be reflected outside of your process._ (https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env). And as I understand the variable should work for exactly this one process. But it doesn't. Does it mean that all `require`s are done before the script is begun parsed? Where can I read more about Node.js bootstrapping process?

Comment: @thefourtheye The module subsystem gets loaded right away and that itself already `require()`s `fs` to load the script supplied on the command line.